# How would I set up my reducer properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to toggle my modal via redux but for some reason I'm getting an error that says: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModalOpen' of undefined` (pointing to the line `isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen` inside `List.js`) which means my root reducer isn't defined properly.  But I'm sure I've defined it properly inside `index.js` file.  What am I doing wrong and how would I be able to resolve this and use these actiontypes properly in order for it to work?

Note:  The `<Modal/>` component is an npm package I installed, I didn't create it on my own.

Here's my `List.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

class List extends Component {
    state = {
       isOpen: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({isActive:!this.state.isActive});
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: false});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <CheckoutButton clicked={this.toggleModal}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
                    <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List);
```

Here's my `reducer.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../action/NoNameAction';

const initialState = {
    isModalOpen: false
};

const global = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.OPEN_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isModalOpen: true,
            }
        case actionTypes.CLOSE_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isModalOpen: false,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default global;
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import modalOpenReducer from './store/reducer/reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    isOpen: modalOpenReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `isOpen` prop of the `Modal` be a boolean instead of a function?

Comment: @Tholle Yes, it should.  I've edited my original post to make the isOpen prop a boolean.  But I still get that same error.

Comment: You are using the state of the `List` component instead of using the Redux state given to the component through props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the reducer file name to `global.js` and in the root.js import it as `global` instead of reducer.And also in the component,change to `this.props.isOpen`

Comment: so, now are you able to toggle the model